# Installing nav2-iron

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ubuntu

I am trying to install nav2. Currently I have Ubuntu 22.04 and Iron for ros.
nav2 requires gazebo but From Ubuntu 22.04 I think they moved to gz not supporting original gazebo. How should I manage this?

Thank you for your advices in advance

Comment: Hello Jieun! Sorry not sure about who you refer by "they moved" to gz. Are you referring to the nav2 team? or the Gazebo team?

Comment: Oh sorry. I guess  I am refering the Gazebo team.

Answer (score 1):

The good old Gazebo now known as Gazebo Classic (or Gazebo11) is still being maintained according to the official [webpage](https://classic.gazebosim.org/#status) until 2025:

> Release Schedule and Roadmap

> Gazebo 11 is the last major release of Gazebo. All currently supported Gazebo versions are still being maintained and may receive new backwards-compatible features and bug fixes until their end-of-life.

> Gazebo 11.0 2020-01-30 EOL 2025-01-29

In Ubuntu 22.04 you have the Gazebo11 package on Ubuntu Jammy directly and use it normally with ROS 2 Iron. Should be fine to use it specially if you are just interested in the Nav2 software and don't need to develop or learn Gazebo Classic.

Said that, the Gazebo team recommends to migrate to the [new Gazebo](https://gazebosim.org/home) simulator (composed by multiple Gazebo libs) and it is probably the good choice looking for the future.

Using the new Gazebo with Nav2 on ROS 2 Iron [seems possible](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/pull/180) but might require to compile Turtlebot 3 packages in a colcon workspace using the `ROBOTIS-GIT:feature-ign_gazebo` branch. Some people have reported to have a working example ready with [Nav2, ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo Fortress](https://discourse.ros.org/t/nav2-example-with-ignition-gazebo-fortress/31174) (recommended in Ubuntu 22.04).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!!! I did not know gazebo classic is gazebo11! That solved my problem